# Отмена fadeOut() при наведении на блок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется код:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('.response').text('Success');
  if ($('.response').fadeIn()) $('.response').delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}

.response {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click Me</div>
<div class="response"></div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы анимация отменялась при наведении на блок `.response`, и как только мышь за границами `.response` `.fadeOut()` срабатывал?

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, можете отметить его принятым, нажав на галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этого [setTimeout()](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#settimeout) и [clearTimeout()](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-cleartimeout):

```js
var timeout;
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('.response').text('Success');
  $('.response').fadeIn();
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.response').fadeOut();
  }, 1000);
});

$('.response').on('mouseover', function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.response').fadeOut();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}

.response {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click Me</div>
<div class="response"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. По порядку.

1) Странная строка:

```
if ($('.response').fadeIn()) $('.response').delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

`$('.response').fadeIn()` возвращает то же самое, что `$('.response')`, т.е. jQuery-объект, который, внутри условия `if (){}` трансформируется в `true`. И тогда использование конструкции `if (){}` абсолютно излишне. Если ее убрать:

```
$('.response').fadeIn();
$('.response').delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

то ничего не изменится.

2) Как написал выше, `$('.response').fadeIn()` возвращает тот же самый jQuery-объект. Таким образом, к объекту можно обратиться лишь единожды, а затем применять все необходимые методы по цепочке:

```
$('.response').text('Success').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

Это не только сократит код, но и сделает его более производительным, т.к. поиск элемента в дереве документа в этом случае производится лишь единожды.

3) По вопросу:

> Как сделать так, чтобы анимация отменялась при наведении на блок `.response`, и как только мышь за границами `.response` `.fadeOut()` срабатывал?

Я переписал ваш код, работающая версия выглядит так:

```
var timeout;

$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('.response').text('Success').fadeIn();
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $('.response').fadeOut();
  }, 1000);
});

$('.response').on({
  mouseenter: function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $('.response').stop().fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Посмотреть в работе можно здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/rf6pkd7f/

Что же там происхдит:

- Как и было, по клику ставим текст "Success" и показываем через `.fadeIn()`;
- Вместо `.delay()` используем `setTimeout()`, чтобы иметь возможность отменить `.fadeOut()` в случае, когда курсор оказался на блоке `.response`;
- Функция `setTimeout()` возвращает идентификатор таймера, который можно использовать для отмены таймера и действия, которое на нем завязано. Этот идентификатор записываем в заранее созданную глобальную переменную `timeout`;
- При помощи метода `.on()` вешаем на `.response` два обработчика - для событий `mouseenter` и `mouseleave`;
- При `mouseenter` (т.е. наведении) мы отменяем таймер функцией `clearTimeout`, чтобы блок не исчез.
- При `mouseleave` (т.е. ухода курсора с элемента) останавливаем анимацию (если `fadeIn()` еще не успел завершиться) методом `.stop()`, после чего прячем блок при помощи `.fadeOut()`.

Настоятельно рекомендую прочесть туториал по jQuery на официальном сайте, если владеете английским - https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/ , или что-то подобное на русском. После чего подобных вопросов у вас станет гораздо меньше.